# Build an Encoder-Decoder

Tags: python, deep-learning

I am new to the deep learning scene, and I am trying to build an Encoder.

```
trainFromTextFile = "train.FROM"
trainToTextFile   = "train.TO"
trainFromText     = open(trainFromTextFile, 'r', encoding='utf-8').read().lower()
trainToText       = open(trainToTextFile, 'r', encoding='utf-8').read().lower()
trainFromSentence = re.split('\n', trainFromText)
trainToSentence   = re.split('\n', trainToText)
trainFromWords = re.split(' |\n', trainFromText)
trainToWords   = re.split(' |\n', trainToText)

print('Found %s sentences from TrainFrom Text' %len(trainFromSentence))
print('Found %s sentences from TrainTo Text' %len(trainToSentence))
print('Found %s words from TrainFrom Text' %len(trainFromWords))
print('Found %s words from TrainTo Text' %len(trainToWords))

trainInput = trainFromSentence[0:1000]
trainTarget = trainToSentence[0:1000]

max_len = 100    # Cut comments after 100 words
max_words = 10000  # Consider the top 10,000 words in the dataset

tokenizerInput = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
tokenizerInput.fit_on_texts(trainInput)

wordInput = tokenizerInput.text_to_word_sequence(trainInput)
sequencesInput = tokenizerInput.texts_to_sequences(trainInput)
sequencesInput = pad_sequences(sequencesInput, maxlen=max_len)  #Pad so all the arrays are the same size

Inputindex = tokenizerInput.word_index
Inputcount = tokenizerInput.word_counts
nInput = len(tokenizerInput.word_counts) + 1

print("Train From File:\n")
print('Found %s sentences.' %len(trainInput))
print('Found %s sequences.' %len(sequencesInput))
print('Found %s unique tokens.' % len(Inputindex))
print('Found %s unique words.' % len(Inputcount))
```

This is what I have so far, and I was wondering how to use the data i have on hand and build an encoder to take in this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally how you build different types of autoencoder [link](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html). But from your question it seems you are interested in sequence-to-sequence prediction using Encoder-Decoder type models, which are primarily based on recurrent neural network. A tutorial on that can be found here [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-encoder-decoder-model-sequence-sequence-prediction-keras/)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It has helped much.  However, I have 1 small little issue.

When I try,
trainInputEncoded = to_categorical([sequencesInput])

It returns (1, 1000, 100, 4305).  Which is the correct shape except for the 1 at axis 0.  Why is an additional axis created? and how can I delete it?

Comment: `to_categorical()` performs one-hot encoding. However, if you want to remove the additional axis, use: `trainInputEncodedNew = trainInputEncoded.reshape(1000,100,4305)`

Comment: many thanks for your help =)  1 last question though, as python and numpy is still pretty new to me, I am not sure if I did it correctly.  As decoder target needs to be 1 step ahead of the decoder input, I assigned it as such:

`sequencesDecoderInput.shape`
 (1000, 100)
`sequencesDecoderTarget = sequencesDecoderInput[ :, 1:100]`

Comment: i can't really figure that now as I don't have the dataset. But yes the output sequence should be 1 step ahead. In the tutorial, he defined it by `target_in = [0] + target[:-1]`